# wxWidgets drawing Panel

Tags: c++, drawing, wxwidgets

I'm doing some application with wxWidgets and I need to draw few images on different panels. In my application there is one main frame, which contains panel, which contains some buttons and text box. I want to  create drawing panels on this panel. I create some simple test class based on wxWidgets Examples to draw some stuff.

```
#include "MiniBitmap.h"

MiniBitmap::MiniBitmap(wxPanel *parent, int x, int y, int width, int height, char *bits) : 
    wxPanel(parent, x, y, width, height) {
        Img = wxBitmap(100,100, wxBITMAP_SCREEN_DEPTH);
}
MiniBitmap::MiniBitmap(wxPanel *parent, wxWindowID Id, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) :
    wxPanel(parent, Id, pos, size) {
}
void MiniBitmap::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent & evt) {
    // depending on your system you may need to look at double-buffered dcs
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void MiniBitmap::paintNow() {
    // depending on your system you may need to look at double-buffered dcs
    wxClientDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void MiniBitmap::render(wxDC&  dc) {
 //   dc.DrawBitmap( Img, 0, 0, false );
    dc.DrawText(wxT("Testing"), 40, 60); 
    dc.SetBrush(*wxGREEN_BRUSH); // green filling
    dc.SetPen( wxPen( wxColor(255,0,0), 5 ) ); // 5-pixels-thick red outline
    dc.DrawCircle( wxPoint(200,100), 25 /* radius */ );
    Refresh();

}
```

In my frame I connect event in Event Table

```
EVT_PAINT(ID_MINI, MiniBitmap::paintEvent)
```

I create MiniBitmap type object dynamically in main frame constructor. I don't know well this library, so I don't know where am I making mistake. Can panel be child of another panel? Or maybe do I wrong connected events?

Comment: There are a lot of things not making sense in this code (e.g. unused `bits` and `Img`) and you don't show the class declaration and its event table, but the worst thing is that you don't actually say what the problem *is*.

Comment: Try using [wxFormBuilder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/) to get your layout correct and in the order that you want.

Comment: Problem is that DC don't draw anything on this panel. Don't bother about unused variables.